# Cant find memory leak in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I've been sitting for hours checking this code after I found out there's a memory leak/error somewhere
Where is that leak? How can it be fixed?
here is Dr.Memory report:

```
Dr. Memory version 2.3.0
         Running "C:\Users\Beni\source\repos\Magshimim_EX8\Debug\Magshimim_EX8.exe"
         Using system call file C:\Users\Beni\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\symcache\syscalls_wow64.txt

         Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 1 byte(s)
         replace_strlen 
             d:\drmemory_package\drmemory\replace.c(412):
         Magshimim_EX8.exe!?                
             ??:0
         Magshimim_EX8.exe!?                
             ??:0
         Magshimim_EX8.exe!?                
             ??:0
         Magshimim_EX8.exe!?                
             ??:0
         Magshimim_EX8.exe!?                
             ??:0
         KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk
             ??:0

         ERRORS FOUND:
               1 unique,     1 total unaddressable access(es)
               0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
               0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
               0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
               0 unique,     0 total handle leak(s)
               0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
               0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of leak(s)
               0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
         Details: C:\Users\Beni\AppData\Roaming\Dr. Memory\DrMemory-Magshimim_EX8.exe.5208.000\results.txt
         WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000005
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE
#define FIRST_TWO_FILES 2
#define FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS 1
#define MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS 2
#define LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS 3

long findLenOfFile(FILE * file);
char* readFile(FILE* f, char* dest, long len);
char menu(char* scanFolder, char* virusSignature);
char** writeFilesFromFolder(char* scanFolder, char ** filesList, int* len);
char* writePart(char* src, char* dest, int length, int* newLen, int part);
int findSignature(char* virusSignature, char* buffer, int sigLen, int bufferLen);
void scanFiles(char* scanFolder, char** filesList, int amountOfFiles, char* virusSignature, long virusLength, char option);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* log = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(argv[1]) + sizeof(char)*strlen("\\Log.txt") + 4);
    FILE* virusSignatureFile = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    long virusLength = 0;
    char** filesList = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * 0);
    char* virusSignature = 0;
    int amountOfFiles = 0;
    char option = 0;
    int i = 0;

    virusLength = findLenOfFile(virusSignatureFile);

    // get the virusSignature as a string and write the files to check into the filesList
    virusSignature = readFile(virusSignatureFile, virusSignature, virusLength);
    filesList = writeFilesFromFolder(argv[1], filesList, &amountOfFiles);

    // create log file
    strcpy(log, "");
    strcat(log, argv[1]);
    strcat(log, "\\Log.txt");
    FILE * logFile = fopen(log, "w");
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    // get scanning option (normal or quick) and continue accordingly
    option = menu(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (option == '0') {
        fprintf(logFile, "Normal Scan\n\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(logFile, "Quick Scan\n\n");
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Results:\n");
    fclose(logFile);

    // initiate scan
    scanFiles(argv[1], filesList, amountOfFiles, virusSignature, virusLength, option);

    fclose(virusSignatureFile);
    free(log);
    free(filesList);
    free(virusSignature);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}



/*
This function will print the scanning folder path and signature path, also will print the option menu to the user of quick or normal scan,
after that function will return user option(0, or other key)
input: scanFolder path (string), virus signature path (also string)
output: user option (char: '0', or other key)
*/
char menu(char * scanFolder, char * virusSignature)
{
    char userOption = '\0';
    printf("Welcome to my Virus Scan!\n\nFolder to scan: %s\nVirus signature: %s\n\nPress 0 for a norman scan or any other key for a quick scan: ", scanFolder, virusSignature);
    userOption = getchar();
    printf("Scanning began...\nThis process may take several minutes...\n\n");
    return userOption;
}


/*
This function writes all files name from folder to the filesList
input: the scanning folder path
output: amount of files
*/
char** writeFilesFromFolder(char * scanFolder, char ** filesList, int* len)
{
    DIR *d = 0;

    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(scanFolder);
    int i = 0;

    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            if (i > 1)
            {
                filesList = (char**)realloc(filesList, sizeof(filesList) + sizeof(char*) + 4);
                *(filesList + (i - FIRST_TWO_FILES)) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(dir->d_name) + 1);
                strcpy(*(filesList + (i - FIRST_TWO_FILES)), (dir->d_name));
            }
            i++;
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    *len = i - FIRST_TWO_FILES; //first two names is "." and ".."
    return filesList;
}

/*
This function will read the contents of a file into a string
input: a file (FILE *) to read from
output: char* with the contents of the file
*/
char* readFile(FILE* f, char * dest, long len)
{
    dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    fread(dest, 1, len, f);
    return dest;
}


void scanFiles(char * scanFolder, char ** filesList, int amountOfFiles, char * virusSignature, long virusLength, char option)
{
    char* log = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(scanFolder) + sizeof(char)*strlen("\\Log.txt") + 1);
    char * buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 0);
    char* subBuffer = 0;
    char* slash = "\\";
    long length = 0;
    char* name = 0;
    int subLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE * f;

    // reopen log file and append to it
    strcpy(log, "");
    strcat(log, scanFolder);
    strcat(log, "\\Log.txt");
    FILE * logFile = fopen(log, "a");

    // iterate over each file
    for (i = 0; i < amountOfFiles; i++)
    {
        name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(scanFolder) + 1 + sizeof(char) * strlen(slash) + sizeof(char) * strlen(*(filesList + i)) + 20);

        // open current file
        strcpy(name, "");
        strcat(name, scanFolder);
        strcat(name, slash);
        strcat(name, *(filesList + i));
        f = fopen(name, "rb");

        length = findLenOfFile(f);

        if (f != NULL) // if file can be accessed
        {
            buffer = readFile(f, buffer, length);
            if (option == '0') { // Normal Mode
                if (findSignature(virusSignature, buffer, virusLength, length))
                {
                    printf("%s - Infected!\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected!\n", name);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%s - Clean\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - Clean\n", name);
                }
            }
            else { // Quick Mode
                subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length, &subLen, FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS); // get first 20%
                if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer, virusLength, subLen))
                {
                    printf("%s - infected! (first 20%%)\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - infected! (first 20%%)\n", name);
                }
                else {
                    free(subBuffer);
                    subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length, &subLen, LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS); // get last 20%
                    if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer, virusLength, subLen))
                    {

                        printf("%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", name);
                        fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", name);
                    }
                    else {
                        subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length, &subLen, MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS); // get the 60% left in the middle
                        if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer, virusLength, subLen))
                        {
                            printf("%s - Infected!\n", name);
                            fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected!\n", name);
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("%s - clean\n", name);
                            fprintf(logFile, "%s - Clean\n", name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                free(subBuffer);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No file found\n");
        }
        free(*(filesList + i));
        free(name);
    }
    fclose(logFile);
    free(log);
    free(buffer);
    getchar();
}


/*
This function will write part of the file (beginning, middle or end) to a string
input: source (string) to take the information from, destination (string) to write a part of the source to it,
       length (int) of the source string, a pointer (int*) to store the new length of the destination string and
       part of the file to write from (int) 1,2 or 3: first 20%, 60% in the middle and last 20% accordingly
output: string containing the desired part of the source string
*/
char* writePart(char *src, char *dest, int length, int *newLen, int part) {
    int i = 0;
    int percentedLength = 0;
    int count = 0;
    percentedLength = (int)(length / 5); // this len is 20% of the entire file's length


    if (part == FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS) // return beginning
    {
        dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * percentedLength);
        *newLen = percentedLength;

        for (i = 0; i < percentedLength; i++)
        {
            *(dest + i) = *(src + i);
        }
    }
    else if (part == MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS)  // return middle
    {
        // allocate space for the middle: The entire file size minus 20% from the start and 20% from the end
        dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (length - 2 * percentedLength));
        *newLen = length - 2 * percentedLength;

        for (i = percentedLength; i < length - percentedLength; i++) {
            *(dest + count) = *(src + i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    else if (part == LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS) // return end
    {
        dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * percentedLength);
        *newLen = percentedLength;

        for (i = length - percentedLength; i < length; i++)
        {
            *(dest + count) = *(src + i);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}

/*
function that finds the length of a file
input: file (FILE *)
output: the file's length (long)
*/
long findLenOfFile(FILE * file)
{
    long length = 0;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return length;
}

/*
function checks whether a file contains the virusSignature. It iterates over each letter of the file and checks
if it is the same as the first letter in the virusSignature. If it is, it checks the rest of the characters and
returns True if a match is found. if not it continues the same process until the end of the file is reached.
input: The virusSignature (string), a buffer with the content of a file (string), the signature's length (int)
       and the buffer's length (int)
output: True if signature is in file, False otherwise
*/
int findSignature(char* virusSignature, char* buffer, int sigLen, int bufferLen)
{
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < bufferLen - (sigLen - 1); i++) {
        if (*(buffer + i) == *virusSignature) // check if a letter is the same as first letter in virusSignature
        {
            found = TRUE;
            // check if the rest of the letters match the signature and stop if one doesn't
            for (j = 1; (j < sigLen) && found; j++) {
                if (*(buffer + (i + j)) != *(virusSignature + j)) {
                    found = FALSE;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                return TRUE; // if we got a match, return true!
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like this is not a leak, but accessing invalid memory somewhere in a `strlen()` function. Recommend you check every `strlen()` function to make sure it's getting a valid pointer (or to a properly-terminated string). My guess it's in `scanFiles()` via the `filesList` parameter.

Comment: If `writeFilesFromFolder()` is given a `scanFolder` that's invalid or does not exist, it returns a bad pointer plus a negative count, and this will completely blow up everything that follows.  Could this be it?

Comment: But the way to solve this problem, and will benefit you for the rest of your career, is to run this *under a debugger* and let it tell you where things are going wrong.   I have looked at code until my eyes were falling out of my head, without success, but running it under a debugger smacked me in the face and told me "You should have done this three days ago".   Yours might do the same to you :-)

Comment: tidbit: when you initialize `char** filesList = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * 0)` in main(), this is just a placeholder for a later `realloc()`, but you don't have to do it this way. Just set `char **fileList = 0` and `realloc()` knows that a null pointer means it's a new allocation.

Comment: sizeof(filelist) is a constant = to the size of a pointer on your platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `realloc` call in `writeFilesFromFolder` has a bug.

It is:

```
filesList = (char **) realloc(filesList, sizeof(filesList) + sizeof(char *) + 4);
```

Notice that the space allocated for `filesList` is *constant*. It does *not* grow as new elements are added, so you have undefined behavior.

This is *not* a memory leak as the tool detected. A memory leak means that you fail to `free` a pointer that goes out of scope.

Rather, you're storing data beyond the end of the area you've allocated, trashing whatever is there, which is probably the [hidden] chain pointer area that `malloc` et. al. use to keep track of allocations.

I'm not sure how either of the `sizeof` factor in, but, `filesList` is a pointer, so `sizeof(filesList)` is constant [either 4 on a 32 bit machine or 8 for 64 bit].

The allocated space has to increase in proportion to `i`.

---

Here is a refactored version of that function that fixes the bug along with some simplification and cleanup:

BTW, don't cast `malloc`: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Also, note that `sizeof(char)` is [by definition] *always* 1 regardless of how many bits a `char` actually has for a given architecture. So, remove any `sizeof(char) *`

Instead of (e.g.):

```
*(filesList + i)
```

It's usually simpler/cleaner to do:

```
filesList[i]
```

Anyway, here's the code:

```
/*
This function writes all files name from folder to the filesList
input: the scanning folder path
output: amount of files
*/
char **
writeFilesFromFolder(char *scanFolder, char **filesList, int *len)
{
    DIR *d = 0;

    struct dirent *dir;

    d = opendir(scanFolder);
    int i = -FIRST_TWO_FILES;

    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (i >= 0) {
                filesList = realloc(filesList,sizeof(*filesList) * (i + 1));
                filesList[i] = strdup(dir->d_name);
            }
            i++;
        }
        closedir(d);
    }

    *len = i;           // first two names is "." and ".."

    return filesList;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Okay, you *do* have memory leaks. And, I've coded up detection and a fix.

Primarily, what you are doing is passing down a buffer pointer to a function (e.g. `readFile` or `writePart`) as an argument (e.g. `dest`).

Then, you are doing:

```
dest = malloc(percentedLength);
```

This *leaks* the *previous* value of `dest`.

Normally, functions that allocate a buffer and return it do *not* take it as an argument. But, after analyzing your code, replacing the `malloc` with a `realloc` prevents the leak.

---

I had to do a complete code review to find this. And, I did several simplifications and cleanups along the way to try to understand your code and isolate possible further issues.

I replaced your allocation/concatenation of filenames with a new function `filejoin`.

I replaced the other `malloc` calls with a macro: `ALLOCME` that detects the memory leaks *before* they happen. This works in conjunction with the [new] `FREEME` macro that replaces the `free` calls.

The default mode is to detect the leak and abort. If you give the program a `-f` option, it will fix the problem. After you analyze and understand what happened, you can change the default to the "fix" mode.

Where possible, I left your original code under `#if 0`

---

A few more style tips:

Keep lines to <= 80 chars.

Don't use "sidebar" comments, particularly on `if` clauses (e.g.):

```
if (...) { // process the file
```

Replace with:

```
// process the file
if (...) {
```

Don't replicate code. When you are replicating similar code [as in where I replaced the code with `filejoin`], this indicates a good place to write a modular function

---

Anyway, here's the refactored and fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE (! FALSE)
#define FIRST_TWO_FILES 2
#define FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS 1
#define MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS 2
#define LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS 3

#define ALLOCME(_ptr,_len) \
    do { \
        _ptr = allocme(_ptr,_len,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__); \
    } while (0)

#define FREEME(_ptr) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr != NULL) \
            free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

void
sysfault(const char *fmt,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap,fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr,fmt,ap);
    va_end(ap);

    exit(1);
}

long findLenOfFile(FILE * file);
char *readFile(FILE * f, char *dest, long len);
char menu(const char *scanFolder, const char *virusSignature);
char **writeFilesFromFolder(const char *scanFolder, char **filesList, int *len);
char *writePart(char *src, char *dest, int length, int *newLen, int part);
int findSignature(char *virusSignature, char *buffer, int sigLen,
int bufferLen);
void scanFiles(const char *scanFolder, char **filesList, int amountOfFiles,
char *virusSignature, long virusLength, char option);

int opt_fixme = 0;

// allocme -- guarded allocation
void *
allocme(void *ptr,size_t len,const char *fnc,int lno)
{

    if (! opt_fixme) {
        if (ptr != NULL)
            sysfault("allocme: leaking ptr=%p len=%zu (from %s at line %d)\n",
                ptr,len,fnc,lno);
    }

    ptr = realloc(ptr,len);

    if (ptr == NULL)
        sysfault("allocme: realloc failure\n");

    return ptr;
}

#ifdef __linux__
const char *slash = "/";
#else
const char *slash = "\\";
#endif

// filejoin -- create filename from directory and file tail
char *
filejoin(const char *dir,const char *tail)
{
    size_t len;
    char *file;

    len = 0;
    len += strlen(dir);
    len += strlen(slash);
    len += strlen(tail);
    len += 1;

    file = malloc(len);
    if (file == NULL)
        sysfault("filejoin: unable to alloc -- %s\n",strerror(errno));

    *file = 0;

    strcat(file,dir);
    strcat(file,slash);
    strcat(file,tail);

    return file;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#if 0
    char *log = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen("\\Log.txt") + 4);
#else
    char *log;
#endif

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'f':
            opt_fixme = ! opt_fixme;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (argc != 2)
        sysfault("usage: <folder_to_scan> <virus_signature_file>\n");

    const char *topdir = argv[0];
    const char *sigfile = argv[1];

    FILE *virusSignatureFile = fopen(sigfile, "rb");
    if (virusSignatureFile == NULL)
        sysfault("main: unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",sigfile,strerror(errno));

    long virusLength = 0;
#if 0
    char **filesList = malloc(0);
#else
    char **filesList = NULL;
#endif
    char *virusSignature = NULL;
    int amountOfFiles = 0;
    char option = 0;

    virusLength = findLenOfFile(virusSignatureFile);

    // get the virusSignature as a string and write the files to check into the
    // filesList
    virusSignature = readFile(virusSignatureFile, virusSignature, virusLength);

#if 1
    fclose(virusSignatureFile);
#endif

    filesList = writeFilesFromFolder(topdir, filesList, &amountOfFiles);

    // create log file
#if 0
    strcpy(log, "");
    strcat(log, argv[1]);
    strcat(log, "\\Log.txt");
#else
    log = filejoin(topdir,"Log.txt");
#endif
    FILE *logFile = fopen(log, "w");

    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\n"
        "Folder to scan:\n%s\n"
        "Virus signature:\n%s\n\n"
        "Scanning option:\n", topdir, sigfile);

    // get scanning option (normal or quick) and continue accordingly
    option = menu(topdir, sigfile);
    if (option == '0') {
        fprintf(logFile, "Normal Scan\n\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(logFile, "Quick Scan\n\n");
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Results:\n");
    fclose(logFile);

    // initiate scan
    scanFiles(topdir, filesList, amountOfFiles, virusSignature, virusLength,
        option);

#if 0
    fclose(virusSignatureFile);
#endif

    FREEME(log);
    FREEME(filesList);
    FREEME(virusSignature);

#ifndef __linux__
    getchar();
#endif

    return 0;
}

/*
This function will print the scanning folder path and signature path, also
will print the option menu to the user of quick or normal scan,
after that function will return user option(0, or other key)
input: scanFolder path (string), virus signature path (also string)
output: user option (char: '0', or other key)
*/
char
menu(const char *scanFolder, const char *virusSignature)
{
    char userOption = '\0';

    printf("Welcome to my Virus Scan!\n\n"
        "Folder to scan: %s\n"
        "Virus signature: %s\n\n"
        "Press 0 for a norman scan or any other key for a quick scan: ",
        scanFolder, virusSignature);
    userOption = getchar();
    printf("Scanning began...\nThis process may take several minutes...\n\n");
    return userOption;
}

/*
This function writes all files name from folder to the filesList
input: the scanning folder path
output: amount of files
*/
char **
writeFilesFromFolder(const char *scanFolder, char **filesList, int *len)
{
    DIR *d = 0;

    struct dirent *dir;

    d = opendir(scanFolder);
    int i = -FIRST_TWO_FILES;

    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (i >= 0) {
                filesList = realloc(filesList,sizeof(*filesList) * (i + 1));
                filesList[i] = strdup(dir->d_name);
            }
            i++;
        }
        closedir(d);
    }

    // first two names is "." and ".."
    *len = i;

    return filesList;
}

/*
This function will read the contents of a file into a string
input: a file (FILE *) to read from
output: char* with the contents of the file
*/
char *
readFile(FILE * f, char *dest, long len)
{

// NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ free the prior value -- memory leak!
    ALLOCME(dest,len);

    fread(dest, 1, len, f);

    return dest;
}

void
scanFiles(const char *scanFolder, char **filesList, int amountOfFiles,
char *virusSignature, long virusLength, char option)
{
#if 0
    char *log = malloc(strlen(scanFolder) + strlen("\\Log.txt") + 1);
#else
    char *log;
#endif
#if 0
    char *buffer = malloc(0);
#else
    char *buffer = NULL;
#endif
    char *subBuffer = NULL;
    long length = 0;
    char *name = NULL;
    int subLen = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f;

    // reopen log file and append to it
#if 0
    strcpy(log, "");
    strcat(log, scanFolder);
    strcat(log, "\\Log.txt");
#else
    log = filejoin(scanFolder,"Log.txt");
#endif
    FILE *logFile = fopen(log, "a");

    // iterate over each file
    for (i = 0; i < amountOfFiles; i++) {
#if 0
        name = malloc(strlen(scanFolder) + 1 + strlen(slash) + strlen(*(filesList + i)) + 20);
#endif

        // open current file
#if 0
        strcpy(name, "");
        strcat(name, scanFolder);
        strcat(name, slash);
        strcat(name, *(filesList + i));
#else
        name = filejoin(scanFolder,filesList[i]);
#endif
        f = fopen(name, "rb");

        length = findLenOfFile(f);

        // if file can be accessed
        if (f != NULL) {
            buffer = readFile(f, buffer, length);

            // Normal Mode
            if (option == '0') {
                if (findSignature(virusSignature, buffer, virusLength, length)) {
                    printf("%s - Infected!\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected!\n", name);
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s - Clean\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - Clean\n", name);
                }
            }

            // Quick Mode
            else {
                // get first 20%
                subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length, &subLen,
                    FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS);

                if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer, virusLength,
                    subLen)) {
                    printf("%s - infected! (first 20%%)\n", name);
                    fprintf(logFile, "%s - infected! (first 20%%)\n", name);
                }

                else {
                    FREEME(subBuffer);

                    // get last 20%
                    subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length, &subLen,
                        LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS);

                    if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer, virusLength,
                        subLen)) {
                        printf("%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", name);
                        fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", name);
                    }

                    else {
                        // get the 60% left in the middle
                        subBuffer = writePart(buffer, subBuffer, length,
                            &subLen, MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS);

                        if (findSignature(virusSignature, subBuffer,
                            virusLength, subLen)) {
                            printf("%s - Infected!\n", name);
                            fprintf(logFile, "%s - Infected!\n", name);
                        }

                        else {
                            printf("%s - clean\n", name);
                            fprintf(logFile, "%s - Clean\n", name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                FREEME(subBuffer);
            }
            fclose(f);
        }
        else {
            printf("No file found\n");
        }

        FREEME(filesList[i]);
        FREEME(name);
    }

    fclose(logFile);
    FREEME(log);
    FREEME(buffer);

    getchar();
}

/*
This function will write part of the file (beginning, middle or end) to a string
input: source (string) to take the information from, destination (string) to
write a part of the source to it, length (int) of the source string, a pointer
(int*) to store the new length of the destination string and part of the file
to write from (int) 1,2 or 3: first 20%, 60% in the middle and last 20%
accordingly
output: string containing the desired part of the source string
*/
char *
writePart(char *src, char *dest, int length, int *newLen, int part)
{
    int i = 0;
    int percentedLength = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // this len is 20% of the entire file's length
    percentedLength = (int) (length / 5);

// NOTE/BUG: this does _not_ free the prior value -- memory leak!

    switch (part) {
    case FIRST_TWENTY_PRECENTS:  // return beginning
        ALLOCME(dest,percentedLength);
        *newLen = percentedLength;

        for (i = 0; i < percentedLength; i++) {
            *(dest + i) = *(src + i);
        }
        break;

    case MIDDLE_SIXTY_PRECENTS:  // return middle
        // allocate space for the middle: The entire file size minus 20% from
        // the start and 20% from the end
        ALLOCME(dest,length - 2 * percentedLength);
        *newLen = length - 2 * percentedLength;

        for (i = percentedLength; i < length - percentedLength; i++) {
            *(dest + count) = *(src + i);
            count++;
        }
        break;

    case LAST_TWENTY_PRECENTS:  // return end
        ALLOCME(dest,percentedLength);
        *newLen = percentedLength;

        for (i = length - percentedLength; i < length; i++) {
            *(dest + count) = *(src + i);
            count++;
        }
        break;
    }

    return dest;
}

/*
function that finds the length of a file
input: file (FILE *)
output: the file's length (long)
*/
long
findLenOfFile(FILE * file)
{
    long length = 0;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return length;
}

/*
function checks whether a file contains the virusSignature.

It iterates over each letter of the file and checks if it is the same as the
first letter in the virusSignature.
If it is, it checks the rest of the characters and returns True if a match is
found.
if not it continues the same process until the end of the file is reached.

input: The virusSignature (string), a buffer with the content of a file
       (string), the signature's length (int)
       and the buffer's length (int)

output: True if signature is in file, False otherwise
*/
int
findSignature(char *virusSignature, char *buffer, int sigLen, int bufferLen)
{
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < bufferLen - (sigLen - 1); i++) {
        // check if a letter is the same as first letter in virusSignature
        if (*(buffer + i) == *virusSignature)
        {
            found = TRUE;

            // check if the rest of the letters match the signature and stop
            // if one doesn't
            for (j = 1; (j < sigLen) && found; j++) {
                if (*(buffer + (i + j)) != *(virusSignature + j)) {
                    found = FALSE;
                }
            }

            // if we got a match, return true!
            if (found) {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```